# REST API call to SoftLayer_Network_Storage/000000/allowAccessFromHost fails with stdClass error

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm posting this request (000000 == Virtual Guest ID, 000001 == iSCSI ID):

```
POST .../SoftLayer_Network_Storage/000001/allowAccessFromHost

{
 "parameters":[
 {
  "typeClassName": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest",
  "hostId": 000000
 }]
}
```

The response I get is: **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

The ID in the URL is the correct ID for the iSCSI device, the ID in the hostId parameter is the ID of my Virtual Guest. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
POST .../SoftLayer_Network_Storage/000001/allowAccessFromHost

{
  "parameters":[
     "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest",
     000000
  ]
}
```

When you create REST request take account that a parameter and an object property are different, in the JSON body you should not put the parameter name, just put the value in the same order. On the other hand, you need to put the property name like in your second API call.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHost

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/allowaccesstonetworkstorage

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish the same thing using this (0000000 == Virtual Guest ID, 00000001 == iSCSI ID):

```
POST .../SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/0000000/allowAccessToNetworkStorage.json

{
 "parameters": 
 [
  {
     "id": 00000001
  }
 ] 
}
```

No idea why the other way doesn't work though.